# Array.map is not a function while the defined constant is array

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend, fetch, rest

I am fetching a collection of rest from a link but i get "map is not a function" error.Why I am get this. please see my code?

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import reactDom from 'react-dom'
import './App.css'
import axious from 'axios'

const App = () => {
  const [user, userset] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axious
      .get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
      .then(response => userset(response.data))
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }, [])
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {user.map(row => (
        <h5>{row.employee_name}</h5>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
export default App
```

also i replace the .map section with below code ,but when i use below code nothing will appear on the screen

```
  {Object.entries(user).map((row)=><p key={Math.random()}>{row.employee_name}</p>)}
```

Comment: Are sure you're getting data from axious call?

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the URL you shared and the code you have there, you seem to be missing one more .data in the parameter to userset function.

Keep in mind that response.data will return the response body JSON, but you resulting object has the following structure

```
{
"status": "value",
"data": [ <user object> ]
}
```

So in order to be referencing the users array you should be using response.data.data

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your code doesn't work, but anyway it's a good practice to use async functions instead of `then`, and written like that the code will work as it should.

```
useEffect(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
        userset(response.data)
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Read explanation of async-await [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).